# Slow debugging with Android studio 2.2 on Marshamallow 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-debug

I have very strange issue while debugging on Samsung galaxy s7 having Marshmallow (6.0), debugging is very slow sometimes I miss the flow but it is working fine with Samsung S6 active and all other devices having Lollipop i.e 5.0. 
What I am missing here is there any additional settings in marshmallow or Android studio 2.2 ?

Comment: what [debug type](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#debug-types) are you using? if `Hybrid`, try `Java`

Comment: I am using Native debugger of Android Studio i.e Java I guess.

Comment: you guess? are you doing ndk stuff?

Comment: No its just an normal application and debugging is working fine with Samsung S6 active device which has lollipop i.e 5.0 but it stuck with galaxy s7 which has marshmallow 6.0.

Comment: did you try `Java` then?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Switching the debug type to Java did not help. The app is slow on Marshmallow but snappy on Lollipop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I don't have any solution for this problem, I just debug app on Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there were many breakpoints added in android studio, then I removed all break points from going to debug->breakpoints and delete all icon in top left.

By doing this, my issue was resolved.